# How can i validate an url and email with python voluptuous?

Tags: python, validation

I want to validate url and email input data with python voluptuous, maybe something like this:

```
schema = Schema({
    Required('url'): All(str, Url()),
    Required('email'): All(str, Email())
})
```

Looking at the source code i see that voluptuous has a built-in Url function, in the case of the email it hasn't, so i want to built my own, the problem is that i don't know have to call this functions inside the schema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**: by now `voluptuous` has Email validator.

You can write your own validator like this

```
import re
from voluptuous import All, Invalid, Required, Schema

def Email(msg=None):
    def f(v):
        if re.match("[\w\.\-]*@[\w\.\-]*\.\w+", str(v)):
            return str(v)
        else:
            raise Invalid(msg or ("incorrect email address"))
    return f

schema = Schema({
        Required('email') : All(Email())
    })

schema({'email' : "invalid_email.com"}) # <-- this will result in a MultipleInvalid Exception
schema({'email' : "valid@email.com"}) # <-- this should validate the email address
```

Comment: This regexp doesn't accept e-mails like vitor+spam@gmail.com, which are valid.

Comment: Well, then you can just simply extend the expression:  `"[\w\.\-\+]*@[\w\.\-]*\.\w+"` ... voila.

Comment: If validation is based on regular expressions, the `Match` function can be used directly instead of writing a whole validator.